# React Router route half-dynamic?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set up React Router to handle

```
<Route path='/:id' component={Component1} />

<Route path='/new?:params' component={Component2} />
```

But it always matches the first one. How do I write it so it'll match the first part of a path ('/new') but get the rest as dynamic when I have the first route in there too?

Here's the whole Switch block...

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
<Route exact path='/new' component={Component2} />
<Route path='/new?:params' component={Component2} />
<Route path='/:id' component={Component1} />
```

example params:
`post?title=Something&subtitle=Something+Else`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `exact` as a prop that tells the `react-router` to check for the route as it is.

```
<Route path='/:id' component={Component1} exact />
<Route path='/new' component={Component2} exact />
```

For query params, you could use an [external library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string) to parse the query.

```
import qs from 'query-string';

console.log(location.search);
//=> '?foo=bar'

// pass the location.search from `react-router`
const parsed = qs.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {foo: 'bar'}
```

Comment: I actually have an exact route set for '/new' that I didn't post. It matches on '/new' but not if there's params because then it isn't an exact match.

Comment: Give an example of params in your `/new` route?

Comment: Updated the switch block and added the params.

Comment: Are you trying to match `post` route with `new`?

Comment: Yes, after I submit the form on /new I want to clear it out, show a message and stay on that page.

Comment: Try making a sandbox, the above example should work. Did you try it? I'm not getting what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'll make a sandbox.